# Authentication on RESTful API on GET requests

Tags: rest, authentication, access-token

So REST architecture implements `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests. I would like to talk about `GET` requests. `http://example.com/api/students` this is a GET request under the `REST` architecture that will give me a list of students in the database.

My question is about authentication. it seems the best way to authenticate on a GET request would be by using an `Access Token`, like `http://example.com/api/students?token=randomstring`

How is this handled serverside, I mean a secuencial process, to prevent somebody from stealing another user's access token and using it. Is the token refreshed on every request and returned along the results or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you should never put credentials (access tokens) in URLs. Its not exactly wrong or prohibited per se - its just bad practice since it makes it impossible to share URLs without exposing secret credentials (think about what would happen if you copied the URL into an e-mail and send it to a friend). Credentials in URLs simply makes it too easy to accidentally expose them to others.

Take the token and stuff it into the HTTP Authorization header instead - that's why we have it. There are many different ways to use that header, but in your case you would want to use the "bearer" token method. Here is an example from the RFC (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750):

```
GET /api/students HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Authorization: Bearer rAndomSTRiNg
```

On the server you check the validity of the token before doing anything else. To prevent others from stealing it you enforce SSL/TLS on the connection.

The token may need to be refreshed - but that depends on how you obtained it and the rest of your infrastructure. Usually you do not need to refresh it for every request - only after a certain time when it is expired.

You may want to look at OAuth2 which defines four basic ways of obtaining access tokens.